xhtml2pdf position header and content
how to position top content after a header, if header height is auto depending the content of header. If the top position of the content is not automatic, it will overlap if there is a change in size.
style.css
      @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
        @frame header_frame {
          -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
          left: 2cm;
          width: 17cm;
          top: 1.5cm;
          height: auto; #keep changing
        }
        @frame content_frame {
          left: 2cm;
          width: 17cm;
          top: 10cm; #here
          height: 14cm;
        }
      }

    <div id="header_content">
     header content height is changing depends on header content
    </div>
    <div id="content_content">
     content of pdf
    </div>

i have try to change top position to auto but cant change
